# MulServer - Client communication: After a shutdown, connected clients can still interact[WHY?]

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, executorservice

**UPDATE:** Thank you very Antoniossss and Peter Lawrey!

I created a Multi-Threaded Server - Client Communication.

I have 3 Classes: Server, Client, RequestHandler.

The server opens a ServerSocket and then starts to listen for clients via accept() and if a client connects, he refers the client's task(some String) to the RequestHandler.

The command important to me is "SHUTDOWN".
If the RequestHandler finds this command, he calls a method within the Server to shutdown.

This method is based on the usage Example of the Executor Service:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html  (if you do not want to click on the link, see the **FAT** text for the method)

**You do not have to read the code provided below, but in case someone is interested in it I am providing it**

**The method of the usage Example:**

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

---

```
public class MulServer_v1 {

protected static int portNumber = 8540;
protected static int max_Clients = 3;
protected static boolean shutdownFlag = false;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
protected ExecutorService executor;
protected static ArrayList<Socket> socketList = new ArrayList<>();

public MulServer_v1(int portNumber, int poolSize) {
}

public void runServer() {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max_Clients);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not create server on specific port");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (!shutdownFlag) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            socketList.add(clientSocket);
            executor.submit(new RequestHandler_v1(clientSocket));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't accept on the Socket");
            executor.shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    shutdownAndAwaitTermination();
}

public void shutdownAndAwaitTermination() {
    System.out.println("Shutting down..");
    executor.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
            // Cancel currently executing tasks
            System.out.println("komme ich hierhin?");

            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        executor.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Serversocket konnte nicht geschlossen werden");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("I got here!");
    for (Socket s : socketList) {
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't close the socket");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MulServer_v1 server = new MulServer_v1(portNumber, max_Clients);
    server.runServer();
}

}
```

---

```
 public class Client_v1 {

    public static final String HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    public static final int PORTNUMBER = 8540;
    private static boolean clientClose = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Client started");

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORTNUMBER);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                // InputStream test = echoSocket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            String userInput;

            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null && !clientClose) {
                out.println(userInput);
                System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
                // if (userInput.equals("BYE")) {
                // break;
                // }

            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + HOSTNAME);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to "
                    + HOSTNAME);
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    protected static void closeClient() {
        clientClose = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RequestHandler_v1 implements Runnable {
    // private final String password = "passwort";
    private final Socket client;
    private boolean closeFlag = false;

    public RequestHandler_v1(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            client.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));) {
        System.out.println("Thread started with name:"
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        String userInput;
        String serverResponse;

        while ((userInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
            serverResponse = processInput(userInput);
            System.out.println("Received message from "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + userInput);
            writer.write("Sever Response : " + serverResponse);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
            if (closeFlag) {
                Client_v1.closeClient();
                MulServer_v1.socketList.remove(client);
                client.close();

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exception: " + e);
    } catch (Exception ex) {


System.out.println("Exception in Thread Run. Exception : " + ex);
}
}
public String processInput(String input) {
    boolean commandFound = false;
    String output = "";
    try {
        if (input.getBytes("UTF-8").length > 255)
            output = "Max string length exceeded";
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Pattern allPattern = Pattern
            .compile("(?<lower>^LOWERCASE\\s.+)|(?<upper>^UPPERCASE\\s.+)|(?<reverse>^REVERSE\\s.+)|(?<bye>^BYE)|(?<shutdown>^SHUTDOWN passwort)");

    Matcher allMatcher = allPattern.matcher(input);
    if (allMatcher.find()) {
        String lower = allMatcher.group("lower");
        String upper = allMatcher.group("upper");
        String reverse = allMatcher.group("reverse");
        String bye = allMatcher.group("bye");
        String shutdown = allMatcher.group("shutdown");
        commandFound = true;
        if (lower != null) {
            output = lower.substring(10).toLowerCase();
        }
        if (upper != null) {
            output = upper.substring(10).toUpperCase();
        }
        if (reverse != null) {
            output = new StringBuilder(reverse.substring(8)).reverse()
                    .toString();
        }
        if (bye != null) {
            output = "BYE";
            closeFlag = true;
        }
        if (shutdown != null) {
            output = "SHUTDOWN";
            MulServer_v1.shutdownFlag = true;
            closeFlag = true;
        }
    } else {
        commandFound = false;
        output = "UNKNOWN COMMAND";
    }

    if (commandFound) {
        output = "OK ".concat(output);
    } else {
        output = "ERROR ".concat(output);

    }
    return output;

}
}
```

---

Now the shutting down works, but new clients can connect after the shutdown. How is that possible? 
This is Sysout I used to check:

Shutting down..

Thread started with name:pool-1-thread-3

Received message from pool-1-thread-3 : .  //<--This (Sending a message) should //NOT be able to happen, since executor.shutdown();  has already been called.

Comment: This post i soo long TLDR :(

Comment: My question contains 10 lines, the method I am refering too is another 10 lines. Everything else is optional as I said..that's not too long I hope.

Comment: Sure i know the answer here

Comment: executor.execute(new RequestHandler_v1(clientSocket)); try `submit` insteed of `execute`. `execute` may be using current thread (insteed of worker)

Comment: I changed it to submit, still the same. If I have several clients connected, everyone connected prior the SHUTDOWN command can interact with the Server.

Comment: But for longer then 10 seconds?(`!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`)

Comment: Yes, sadly even after the timelimit is exceeded

Comment: As the method suggests a ServerSocket accepts new connections and stopping it just prevents new ones.

Comment: I bet everything will be as you want if you try to connect once more after 10 seconds - other workers will die in another 10 seconds

Comment: @PeterLawrey the awaitTermination closes the socket after the given amount of time, therefore it should stop the existing ones as well.

Comment: awaitTernimation waits for the ExceutorService to shutdown/terminate, it doesn't close anything.

Comment: @Antoniossss Still not working.. I have read about that "Poison Pill" attempt here, too. I am really out of options

Comment: @PeterLawrey  shutdownNow():
Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

Comment: shotdownNow() can set the interrupted flag of each task.  None of your tasks check this flag. In your case, all this does is prevent new tasks from starting.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean now. 
The only threads I have are in my RequestHandler - if I get you right, I need to check in my client class tho - is that right?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am having trouble implementing this. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your signaling is broken:

```
   while (!shutdownFlag) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                executor.execute(new RequestHandler_v1(clientSocket));

            } catch (IOException e) {
```

`accept()` is blocking operation - it blocks until new connection comes right? And here is the culrpit. After you send your "shutdown" command, current thread will unblock, submit the tast, **pass the while condition** and **block again** on `accept()`. After this, proper executor will set the flag to false, but server is still `accepting` so pool is never shut down. 
Another attempt to connect should wake the server and honor `shutdownFlag` breaking out of the loop and causing all handlers to die after 10 seconds.

Also:

```
while ((userInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

is a blocking operation - it block your tasks from finishing thus pool will newer shut down. `null` will be returned if stream will end - either naturally or by an exception. You are not ending the stream on neither of sides. So it will block.

ExecutorsService#shutdownNow() does not mean that threads from pool will be killed - they are signalled to terminate, and threads are to gracefully terminate just like @PeterLawrey mentioned, using Thread.isTerminated() flag.

Comment: I started another client after 10 seconds, I can still communicate with server with the others.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem! I just got the "Pool did not terminate" error message, so you are on the right track! How do I fix that?
Should I create another FLag within the client and make the loop like this:
while ((userInput = in.readLine()) != null && !myFlagIjustCreated)

Comment: U got following options 1) Do not use blocking I/O (and handle interruption flag propertly) 2) close all sockets on server side. Second one is much more easier. Just keep track of all client sockets you have accepted and close them all in case of "shutdown" command.

Comment: So my Server class should have an ArrayList with all the client sockets in it and then I iterate over it?
And do you have any suggestion where to read more about option 1?

Comment: Yes this is one of possibilities and it widely used in server applications. Sockets are basicly blocking IO stream based, so you would have to write wrappers. You can read about Java NIO but i would stick to the simple socket closing.

Comment: So I put this at the end of my AwayTermination method
for(Socket s : socketList){
   if(s!=null)
    try {
     s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Couldn't close the socket");
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
Still doesn't work - it never reaches this part of the code.

Comment: @InDaPond it **must** work as sockets will be closed and blocking IO will rise an exception. Are you sure that socket closing actually happen? (sysout that)

Comment: Uhm, now I put it into the first if(branch) and it kinda works..but an already solved problems arises: a new client can connect even after the SHUTDOWN   (within the 10 second span)
I am close to crying here^^

Comment: FIRST: With the ArrayList, after 10 seconds every client is CLOSED. Thank you for that
BUT: Now new clients are able to connect after the SHUTDOWN, this makes 0 sense to me, since the first call within the method is 
executor.shutdown();

Comment: @InDaPond why after 10 seconds? This should be instant. You are doing something wrong that is not visible in currently shown code.

Comment: I updated the code, see the very last section. Oh and I am doing it after 10 seconds b/c I wanted to have the 10s waiting time - would be instant if I put that in front of the awaitTermination.

Comment: U still there :(?

Comment: @InDaPond analize the proof of concept and try to adjust to it.
You should close the sockets and then await termination not the other way around because you close socket to ALLOW tasks to terminate, then how dou expect task to finish if it blocked? Closing socket will unblock the task. Try to understand the code I have attach in onther answer. You can use multiple clients with executorservice as well, and you will see, that closing client connection on server side will do the trick

Comment: I am confused. I implemented your proof of concept and this is the output
Will try to read
Read a
 So it did reach the Read a block.
And I just tried putting the for statement in front of the executor.awaitTermination       .-   then a still existing client still won't be closed as long as i keep hitting a button on my keyboard every few seconds

Comment: @InDaPond it DID reach the read block, blocked on it, an released on socket close. Read the comment! If you comment: *If you comment* (remove) *client.close(); app will never end just like in your case.*

Answer (score 1):

Proof of concept that closing the socket will break from blocked IO operation:
public class Buffers {
    private static Socket client;

```
static class ServerThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverS = new ServerSocket(1099);
            client = serverS.accept();
            client.getOutputStream().write('a');
            client.getOutputStream().flush();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

static class ClientThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1099);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Will try to read");
            String line=null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) { // block here
                System.out.println("Read " + line); // will never come here
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Server closed the connection!");
        }
        super.run();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new ServerThread().start();
    ClientThread t = new ClientThread();
    t.start();
    t.join();

}
```

If you comment `client.close();` app will never end just like in your case.

Comment: I actually want the server to let the clients communicate with them for a certain amount of time, to make this work I had to make everything static which is super ugly imo, but it works!! Thank you so much